# SSH client/server confusion

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

The one thing that's been bothering me is, there is always concept of "ssh-ing" from client to server.

Might be a trivial question, but I just want to clear my mind. Which one do I choose to install on my host machine, `openssh-server` or `openssh-client`? How do I know if I want to install `openssh-server` or `openssh-client` on my or any other local or remote machine?

Let's say I want to ssh from client1 to client2. Do I have to install `openssh-client` or `openssh-server` on client2 and vice versa?

Comment: Think of `ssh` as a way to access a system.
The system being accessed is the server, the one *reaching out* to the other system is the client. Another way to look at it, you will be typing at the client, things will happen at the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openssh-client` contains the ssh client program `/usr/bin/ssh`, you use this to connect **TO** other machines running `sshd` or some other compatible ssh daemon.   This package also contains  other client-side programs like `scp`, `sftp`, `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-agent`, `ssh-copy-id`, and more.

`openssh-server` contains the ssh daemon `/usr/sbin/sshd` and the necessary startup scripts so that it gets started at boot time. This is used to listen for and handle incoming ssh connections **FROM** other machines.

You can have either or both (or neither) installed on a machine, depending on what role(s) (client and/or server) you want that machine to play.

In short:

- to accept incoming ssh connections, install openssh-server
- to make outbound ssh connections, install openssh-client
- to do both, install both

Comment: Or even simpler: Just install both. SSH is not the kind of thing that bloats your system, plus many other tools you'll most likely use depend on SSH (e.g. Git).

Answer (score 3):

I think you've actually already answered your own question? If you want to ssh from client to server you'd install the client part on the client and the server part on the server.

If you want "*to ssh from client1 to client2*" you're actually wanting to ssh from client ("client1") to server ("client2"). The client is where you're originating the connection and the server is where you're going to. So if you want to ssh from client2 to client1 then you'd install the client software on client2 and the server component on client1.

There's nothing stopping you having client and server software on the same machine.